AWS cognito custom claims can't access by token
I try to add custom claims to my AWS cognito token as you can see:
 public async Task<SignInDto> SignInAsync(string username, string password)
 {
     var result = await _personRepository.GetMspIdAndBranchIdByUsername(username);
     var authParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     authParameters.Add("USERNAME", username);
     authParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);
     authParameters.Add("SECRET_HASH", CalculateSecretHash(_cognitoOptions.AppClientId, _cognitoOptions.AppClientSecret, username));

     var authRequest = new InitiateAuthRequest
     {
         ClientId = _cognitoOptions.AppClientId,
         AuthParameters = authParameters,
         AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
     };

     try
     {
         var response = await _cognitoService.InitiateAuthAsync(authRequest);
         var authenticationResult = response.AuthenticationResult;

         var customClaims = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
             { "branchId", result.BranchId.ToString() }, 
         };

         var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

         var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(response.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken);

         foreach (var claim in customClaims)
         {
             token.Payload[claim.Key] = claim.Value;
         }
         
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authenticationResult.AccessToken)) 
              return new SignInDto("", "", "");

         return new SignInDto(/*authenticationResult.AccessToken*/handler.WriteToken(token), authenticationResult.IdToken, authenticationResult.RefreshToken);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         return new SignInDto("", "", "");
     }
 }

As you can see I added branchid into the claims.
When I call my application API with the generated token which you can see here:
eyJraWQiOiI5MGtNcnhsRk1rNlVpMXdwRGplM0xpNXFHbW1ObWI1cEpWRXh1TG4zT2RnPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.

I couldn't access the branchId claim using this code and the claims are null
 Guid.TryParse(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User?.FindFirst("branchId")?.Value, out var branchId);
 BranchId = branchId;

Would you please let me know if I should config a setting in AWS console?
